# Custom Controller Action update_attribute returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create my first custom controller actions for my final school project.

The value of the approved_at attribute returns nil after I attempt to update it.

The view shows no errors, the flash returns successful. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

If I did not provide enough information please let me know in the comments and I will add the required files.

**registry_requests_controller.rb**

```
class RegistryRequestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @registry_requests = RegistryRequest.all
  end

  def show
    @registry_request = RegistryRequest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def approve
    @approval = RegistryRequest.find(params[:id])

    if @approval.save
      @approval.update_attribute(:approved_at, true)

      flash[:notice] = "The vehicle was approved for the Registry."
      redirect_to request.referer
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error approving the vehicle. Please try again."
    end
  end

  def deny
    @registry_request.where(denied_at: true)
  end
end
```

**rails console**

```
irb(main):003:0> RegistryRequest.first
  RegistryRequest Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "registry_requests".* FROM "registry_requests"  ORDER BY "registry_requests"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<RegistryRequest id: 1, approved_at: nil, denied_at: nil, notes: nil, vehicle_id: 31, created_at: "2015-07-23 14:01:26", updated_at: "2015-07-23 14:01:26">
```

**raise parameters**

```
Parameters:

{"_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"F9RwL4WZbo8fXnjLqnQaG5gpVxW60JGSuqq5hPEeCJKGwPolJTNRIOmzyrX/HAsEmlwLQ9CXfS9PmNcK1OL9+A==",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

**registry_requests#show**

```
<div><%= @registry_request.vehicle.make %></div>
<div><%= @registry_request.vehicle.model %></div>
<div><%= @registry_request.vehicle.description %></div>
<%= link_to "Approve", approve_registry_request_path, method: :patch %>
<%= link_to "Deny", deny_registry_request_path(request), method: :patch %>
```

**Registry Request migration**

```
class CreateRegistryRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :registry_requests do |t|
      t.datetime :approved_at
      t.datetime :denied_at
      t.text :notes
      t.references :vehicle, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**What I have attempted**

I have tried adding .save to the if @approval, and added @approval.save underneath the update_attribute line. If I use update_attributes the error is thrown saying 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)'.

**Edit: Server Log**

```
Started PATCH "/registry_requests/1/approve" for ::1 at 2015-07-27 10:47:15 -0400
Processing by RegistryRequestsController#approve as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"trCMgfHPT0LL5fOxVDmQyzRmpyFF4B/WeUHtzkvyHR0npAaLUWVw7T0IQc8BUYHUNhP7dy+n82uMc4NAbg7odw==", "id"=>"1"}
  RegistryRequest Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "registry_requests".* FROM "registry_requests" WHERE "registry_requests"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/registry_requests/1
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


Started GET "/registry_requests/1" for ::1 at 2015-07-27 10:47:15 -0400
Processing by RegistryRequestsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  RegistryRequest Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "registry_requests".* FROM "registry_requests" WHERE "registry_requests"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Vehicle Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "vehicles".* FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 31]]
  Rendered registry_requests/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
Completed 200 OK in 72ms (Views: 71.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Comment: `update_attributes` take a hash, which is usually something like `registry_request_params`. That would be a private method with strong params of attributes updated. Calling that method is the _one_ argument for `update_attributes`. Otherwise, you would pass a hash like so: `update_attributes(approved_at: true)`.

Comment: Also, to clarify, how is this controller being used? I assume it is not related to a form, because there is no `registry_requests_params` defined...

Comment: I added the show view that it is being used in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `approved_at` is a `datetime field` and while updating the value, `boolean` is passed.
Try updating `approved_at` attribute with current timestamp as shown below.

```
def approve
  @approval = RegistryRequest.find(params[:id])
  if @approval.update_attribute(:approved_at, Time.now)
    flash[:notice] = "The vehicle was approved for the Registry."
    redirect_to request.referer
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error approving the vehicle. Please try again."
  end
end
```

Comment: I do not believe so, because Rails Console would show that value.

Comment: Could you post the server log when this method is invoked.

Comment: What is the datatype of the field `approved_at`? Also why dont you try reloading your `rails c` and trying `RegistryRequest.first`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84380/discussion-between-jonathan-musso-and-ojash).